# Clear contents of specific listview columns?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

This is how I currently add info to my listview:

```
private void toolStripMenuItem2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int totItems = Seq3.Count - 1;
    if (PercentPopTolerance1.Count - 1 > totItems) totItems = PercentPopTolerance1.Count - 1;

    for (int i = 0; i <= totItems; i++)
    {
        ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem();
        string item1 = "";
        string item2 = "";

        if (Seq3.Count - 1 >= i) item1 = Seq3[i].ToString();
        if (PercentPopTolerance1.Count - 1 >= i) item2 = PercentPopTolerance1[i].ToString();

        lvi.SubItems.Add(item1);
        lvi.SubItems.Add(item2);

        listView2.Items.Add(lvi);
    }
}
```

View of empty listview:

[image]

Now how would I clear the contents of any particular column? Say I want to add to column YYMM but before I do this, I want to **clear that particular column**. How would this be done?

Answer (score 1):

You should specify a column by its name (a column corresponds to a subitem in a ListViewItem), note that this `Name` is not `ColumnHeader.Name`, I mean the corresponding `ListViewSubItem.Name`:

```
public void ClearColumn(string colName){
  foreach(ListViewItem item in listView1.Items){
    var cell = item.SubItems[colName];
    if(cell != null) cell.Text = "";
  }
}
```

The following code will work for `ColumnHeader.Name` passed in instead of `ListViewSubItem.Name` as the code above does:

```
public void ClearColumn(string columnHeaderName){
  int i = listView1.Columns.IndexOfKey(columnHeaderName);
  if(i == -1) return;
  foreach(ListViewItem item in listView1.Items){
    item.SubItems[i].Text = "";
  }
}
```

You can try the following code to make it work for `Text` instead of `Name`:

```
public void ClearColumn(string colText){
  if(listView1.Items.Count == 0) return;
  var col =  listView1.Columns.Cast<ColumnHeader>()
                      .Select((x,i)=>new{x,i})
                      .FirstOrDefault(a=>a.x.Text == colText);
  if(col == null) return;
  foreach(ListViewItem item in listView1.Items){
    item.SubItems[col.i].Text = "";
  }
}
```

Comment: Stupid question but does assigning a specific datatype to the cell matter or can i leave it as "var"

Comment: @Newuser `var` is just for convenience, in this case we already know that `SubItems[key]` would return a `ListViewSubItem`

Comment: I tried your approach but I'm not getting results. Should it be column name or column text which I put into the method? This is because "Seq #" is set using edit column text, not name @king king

Comment: @Newuser the code I posted works only if you specify the `Name` property for your `ListViewSubItem` (when you add the `ListViewSubItem` to the `SubItems` of a `ListViewItem`)

Comment: @Newuser I've added code to search a column by Text, it may be more convenient for you in this case.

Comment: Still not having any luck with the first 2 approaches. My listview is called listview2, i changed it to that but no luck

Comment: @Newuser You might not know how to use the 2 first approaches, try the third one with this code `ClearColumn("YYMM");`

Answer (score 1):

You can clear column values like this

```
        var items = listView1.Items;

        foreach (ListViewItem item in items)
        {
            a.SubItems["YYWW"].Text = "";
        }
```